# i'm having some difficulties with setting status from false to true with firebase set() method

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update a field when a button Is clicked then change status from `false` to `true` from a list of items when. What it does currently it adds a new field instead of updating it. `updated()`method didn't work as well it does the same.

```js
 taskref.child("users").child(authData.uid).child("task").on('value', function(snapshot) {

   $scope.list = [];
   snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
     $scope.list.splice(0, 0, child.val());
     $scope.taskKeys = function() {
       return Object.keys($scope.list);
     }
   });
 });

 $scope.complete = function() {
   $scope.status = taskref.child("users").child(authData.uid).child('task').child("status").set(true);
}
```

```html
<ion-list ng-controller="allTasksCtrl">
  <ion-item class="item-button-right tasks" ng-repeat="t in taskKeys()">{{list[t].title}} : {{list[t].description}}
    <button ng-click="complete()" class="button button-positive">
      <i class="ion-ios-checkmark"></i>
    </button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

[image]

Comment: Aren't you missing another child of ID between task and status?

Comment: so previously i've done it like it like this $scope.status = taskref.child("users").child(authData.uid).child('task').child(key).child("status").update({status:true}); but the problem with this is that it sets integer id's for these items inseated of upating the current ones

Comment: How about `taskref.child("users").child(authData.uid).child('task').child(key).update({status:true});`

Comment: nah this doesn't work too..